# Implementing an adapter for RecyclerView in Android

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement the flexible space with image pattern of the material design.

In order to do so, I followed [this tutorial](http://blog.grafixartist.com/toolbar-animation-with-android-design-support-library/).

The problem is, the tutorial uses `RecyclerView`, and I have another view I'd like to use which is just a simple `ScrollView` with a relative view:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/loggedInTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/separator1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/profile_logged_in_with_title"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/loggedInPlatformLogo"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/loggedInTitle"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/loggedInTitle"
            android:background="@drawable/facebook_logo"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/separator2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/separator1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/loggedInTitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/homeIcon"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/loggedInTitle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/separator2"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/home_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/homeTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/homeIcon"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/homeIcon"
            android:text="@string/profile_home_title"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/homeAddressEdit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/homeIcon"
            android:layout_below="@+id/homeIcon"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/profile_home_address_hint"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/separator3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/separator1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/homeAddressEdit"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/workIcon"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/homeIcon"
            android:layout_below="@+id/separator3"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/work_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/workTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/workIcon"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/workIcon"
            android:text="@string/profile_work_title"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/workAddressEdit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/workIcon"
            android:layout_below="@+id/workIcon"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/profile_work_address_hint"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/separator4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/separator1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/workAddressEdit"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/privacyIcon"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/workIcon"
            android:layout_below="@+id/separator4"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:background="@drawable/privacy_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/privacyTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/privacyIcon"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/privacyIcon"
            android:text="@string/profile_privacy_title"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/privacySpinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/privacyIcon"
            android:layout_below="@+id/privacyIcon"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:entries="@array/profile_privacy_settings"
            android:prompt="@string/profile_privacy_title" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

So I tried to replace the RecyclerView in the tutorial's layout xml with a reference to this view, but the result is I can't scroll the view. **I guess that's because `ScrollView` is not compatible with the flexible space pattern**.

Next attempt was trying to convert the above `ScrollView` layout to an adapter in order to use `RecyclerView` [following this Android Developers example](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html), but I have no idea how to do that, since I got too many elements to combine and the example consists of simple array of Strings.

I'd really appreciate a sample of how the Adapter should look like in order to match the layout above, or another easier solution (maybe RecyclerView isn't the best direction), if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

There's a design support library from Google. 
Try this website:
http://hmkcode.com/material-design-app-android-design-support-library-appcompat/

Comment: The example there is with Cards View, and obviously I don't need Cards View as it would look very different from the initial layout...